# Property 'type' does not exist on type 'unknown' error caused by Pipe searchByType

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am receiving various errors like P

> roperty does not exist on type 'unknown'

after I do

> ionic build --prod --release

```
src/app/pages/top-media/top-media.page.ts:18:16
18   templateUrl: './top-media.page.html',
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TopMediaPage.


 Error: src/app/pages/top-media/top-media.page.html:106:36 - error TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

106        <ng-container *ngIf="media?.type==='T'">
```

html

```
     <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="topMediaSet($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="circles" refreshingSpinner="crescent" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
            </ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="danger" (click)="filter('V')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="success" (click)="filter('A')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="volume-high-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="tertiary" (click)="filter('T')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="document-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="warning" (click)="filter('P')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="camera-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

 <ion-row *ngFor="let media of topMedia | filterByType: mediaType | slice:1;  let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="media?.type==='T'">
    {{media?.message | slice:0:2000}}
</p>
```

The problems occurs when i use the filter I created | filterByType: mediaType

ts

```
topMedia:any =[];

mediaType:string = '';


constructor(
...
) { 
  this.topMediaSet();
}


topMediaSet(refresher?:any) {
this.offset = 0;
if (typeof refresher == 'undefined') {
    this.loading = true;
}
this.userData.topMedias(this.offset).pipe(
map((data: any) => {
   if (data.success) {
      this.topMedia = data.topMedia;
   }
   if (typeof refresher != 'undefined') {
            refresher.target.complete();
    }
    this.loading = false;
 })
).subscribe()
}


 filter(mediaType: string) {
  this.mediaType = mediaType;
  console.log(mediaType);
}
```

filter pipe

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByType',
})
export class FilterByTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
/**
 * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
 */
transform(items: any[], type: any): any {

    if (!items) return [];
    if (!type) return items;
    type = type.toLowerCase();
    console.log('type', type);
    return items.filter(it => {
        if (it.type) {
            return it.type.toLowerCase().includes(type);
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

I am getting this error if i put

> filterByType: mediaType |

If I REMOVE THIS LINE FOR THE NGFOR I AM NOT GETTING ANY ERRORS BUT I NEED THE FILTER. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the direct answer, but I invite you to do a little way to reproduce, I can dig deeper on why this doesn't work.

As an alternative and probably a better way for this, you'd be better reacting to the filter() function used on the button and modifying at that point the array of the ngFor with a new reference

```
this.topMedia = results
this.topMediaFiltered = results

[...]

filter(mediaType: string) {
  this.topMediaFiltered = this.topMedia.filter(it => it.type === mediaType) || [];
  this.mediaType = mediaType;
}
```

In the template use topMediaFiltered instead of topMedia